# What ORM solutions are available for Kohana 3.1?

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

Kohana 3.0 used to have Sprig, Jelly, etc. alongside with its default ORM system. As far as I understand, Kohana 3.1 is not compatible with Sprig and Jelly and its default ORM is still in development. What to use for ORM in Kohana 3.1 then?

Comment: Just for curiosity, why you don't like Kohana's default ORM? I'm using it in production and it works really nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find 3.1 modules at Github:

[Jelly for 3.1](https://github.com/creatoro/kohana-jelly-for-Kohana-3.1/) (unofficial fork, Banks and Jonathan Geiger have no time for development)

[Sprig branch for 3.1](https://github.com/sittercity/sprig/tree/feature/kohana-3.1)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Leap ORM for Kohana](http://orm.spadefootcode.com/).  You can download it off github at https://github.com/spadefoot/kohana-orm-leap

This ORM is designed to work with Kohana 3.0.X, Kohana 3.1.X, and Kohana 3.2.  It works with all major databases (including MySQL, MariaDB, PostgresSQL, MS SQL, DB2, Oracle, Firebird, and Sqlite) unlike the other Kohana ORMs that I have seen.  Expanding the ORM is extremely easy whereas Kohana's default ORM cannot be adapted to work with such databases without a lot of work.

It is pretty well documented.  Unlike other ORMs for Kohana that I have seen, it can handle composite primary keys and can use more than integers as primary keys (e.g. strings).  It also give you the flexibility to switch the database driver from the standard PHP extensions to PDO using a simple config file.

Comment: For a long time I have been looking for an ORM that works well with other databases.... Leap was the first solution that I found that actually did it right.  K3 ORM and Jelly were just not cutting it because I couldn't use composite keys.  Doctrine is way too old and is not really for Kohana.  Same with PHP ActiveRecord.  Go with LEAP...it is will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [PHP ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/)? It is an ActiveRecord style ORM with validations, realtionships, eager loading, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you to use:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm

I have used both the default ORM in Kohana 3.0 (should be similar to the one in 3.1) and the doctrine ORM in big projects.

Doctrine is great. Everything you wan't is there. Even for very special and tricky cases. If you use the default Kohana 3 ORM you will end up extending it because it is to simple.

The configuration part in Doctrine can be a little scary because there are a lot of options. In the long run it is really worth it though :)